# How to perform post request in header and body in JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, web-services

I'm using JSON and want to send post request to server via username, password in body and x-auth-app-id, x-auth-app-hash in header..

I have test on Postmen and it return 200 (status ok), But when I build my sources it happen error.

This is my class header:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;


public class HttpRequestUtil {
    public static JSONObject httpRequest(String requestUrl, String requestMethod, String outputStr) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    InputStream inputStream=null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
        HttpURLConnection httpUrlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpUrlConn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpUrlConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpUrlConn.setUseCaches(false);

        httpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("x-auth-app-id", "6166611659356156223");
        httpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("x-auth-app-hash", "a44f4ea21475fa6761392ba4bc659990bee771c413b2c207490a79f9ec78c2a61234");
        httpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        httpUrlConn.setRequestMethod(requestMethod);

        if ("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(requestMethod))
            httpUrlConn.connect();

        if (null != outputStr) {
            OutputStream outputStream = httpUrlConn.getOutputStream();
           
            outputStream.write(outputStr.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            outputStream.close();
        }
        
        inputStream = httpUrlConn.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        String str = null;
        while ((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(str);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStreamReader.close();
        
        inputStream.close();
        inputStream = null;
        httpUrlConn.disconnect();
      jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(buffer.toString());
    }

    catch (ConnectException ce) {
          ce.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("Our server connection timed out");
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           System.out.println("https request error:{}");
    }

    finally {
        try {
            if(inputStream!=null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
}
```

And class Body:

```
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import net.sf.json.JSONException;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

public class CallCenterController {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    String sipUser = "vchi_dd";
    String sipPassword = "m9Bp7s+CtQj85HygnIFjPn7O4Vithrunaa";

    Map<String, Object> sipAccount = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    sipAccount.put("sipUser", sipUser);
    sipAccount.put("sipPassword", sipPassword);

    sipAccount = postData(sipUser, sipPassword);
    System.out.println("result: " + sipAccount);
};

public static JSONObject postData(String sipUser, String sipPassword) {
    String url="https://myservice.com/oapi/v1/call/click-to-call/02437590555&sipUser="+sipUser+"&sipPassword="+sipPassword;
    return HttpRequestUtil.httpRequest(url, "POST", "");
 }
}
```

When I build it happen an exception following as:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://myservice.com/oapi/v1/call/click-to-call/02437590555&sipUser=vchi_dd&sipPassword=m9Bp7s+CtQj85HygnIFjPn7O4Vithrunaa
  https request error:{}
  result: null
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at com.mypackage.HttpRequestUtil.httpRequest(HttpRequestUtil.java:63)
at com.mypackage.CallCenterController.postData(CallCenterController.java:45)
at com.mypackage.CallCenterController.main(CallCenterController.java:34)
```

How to send correct data to my url and fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Java HTTP Client API if your java version is high enough.
Here's a link to it https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-http-client

I have used it and it feels more maintainable and clear.

Also, it seems that you're sending the request with empty body even though you say in your question that you are sending username and password in body.
And why are you adding username and password to a map if you are not using the map?

> sipAccount.put("sipUser", sipUser);
>
> sipAccount.put("sipPassword", sipPassword);

Comment: I will try with your suggestion